# Entity Framework Code First table naming issue, singular confilcts with Plural

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 table which I'm trying to access in MVC, one called Employees and one called Accountable. This is my code: -

```
public class dbEntity: DbContext
{
public dbEntity(): base("name=dbEntity") {}
public DbSet<Accountable> Accountable { get; set; }
public DbSet<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is the code complains that it can't find the table 'Accountables', I know I can add this line: -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); }
```

But then the code complains that it can't find 'Employee'. At the moment it is not practical to rename the tables, is there another way around it?

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming you are trying trying to do ef code first with an existing database. Try adding `[Table("TableName")] ` to your context class declaration.

Comment: That seemed to resolve it, thanks very much

Comment: Great! Please accept me answer so others will be able to benefit from your question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a data annotation of your table's name in the database to your context class.

`[Table("TableName")]`